# Javascript Highcharts: series datalabel formatter function to loop data not formatting all data form the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach, highcharts

I'm running into an issue where the formatter method is not taking in all the data from the array. For example:

```
   var test = [1234, 4567, 1564, 7899];

   chartData.plotOptions.series.datalabels.formatter = function () {
       for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
           // formatNumber() is a dummy method in this example
           return formatNumber(test[i]);
       }
   };

   After the loop, the datalabel only shows the first index data on each segment of bar chart.
```

The result returns the first index only. I'm not sure why it's not looping through the whole array. Can someone please give me some assistance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will `return` after the first iteration of the `for` loop, which is why you only see the first index.

That said, the `formatter` is a callback that gets applied to each data point, so you shouldn't need to loop over your test values. You should try something like:

```
chartData.plotOptions.series.datalabels.formatter = function() {
    return formatNumber(this.y);
}
```

Refer to the [`formatter` documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.formatter) for available data to use.